# Why is my if statement not breaking the for loop, despite the condition being satisfied?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, break

I have a loop. This loop has the job of executing a list of functions, one by one. 
One of the parts of the function has the role of setting the variable game_exit to "1" if the user inputs the code "exite".
I have confirmed that the function sets game_exit to "1" when asked to, and that the variable is globalised.

My issue is that, despite game_exit being equal to "1" both in the function and the if statement, the code refuses to break the for loop. It simply ends the function, and continues with the next entry in the list.

The program itself runs without any other issues.

```py
#game__ execute the game__game_function function for each question and answer set.
time.sleep(1.5)
for function in game__functions:
    if game_exit == "1":
        break
    else:
        game__functions()
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough code or output to see whether `game_exit` can actually be the string `"1"` or if it is actually an int `1` or boolean `True`. You should (really learn to) use a debugger and step through your code, or at least add the following print statements to your code and add the resulting output to your question:

```py
for function in game__functions:
    print(game_exit, type(game_exit), game_exit == "1")
    if game_exit == "1":
        print('breaking the loop')
        break
    else:
        print('NOT breaking the loop')
        game__functions()
print('loop exited')
```

these will provide you with feedback about the actual details of your code execution.

Comment: As stated in my question, I have ensured that the value game_exit is equal to "1" in all scenarios.

Comment: just to be sure, the code shown in your question is not the actual code? please try providing at least a minimal working example, as it is almost impossible to guess what you wrote and therefore why it seems such that the code is not breaking the loop.